Reconciling bonding and antibonding MOs with how reactions proceed
Take the reaction between MeI and some nucleophile (Nu:) to give Me-Nu. Does the approach of the Nu, provide the energy input necessary to promote the Me-I electrons to the antibonding MO? Do the Me-I bond electrons exist in both the bonding and antibonding MOs (just at different frequencies)? It's been a little hand-wavy in class, so I am an not sure "when" the antibonding MOs are considered occupied (and when the new bonding MO is formed)?

It's Nu's lone pair that overlaps with antibonding MO, weakening Me-I bond.
